# Django Queryset Combine Each User With Groups?

Tags: django-queryset, python-3.6, django-1.11

I am developing Django app, where I need to display all the `users` with groups they belong to. now i am getting results like follow

My user Model Has the following fields mentioned in the [django auth model link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)

my queryset like follow:

```
User.objects.values("pk","email","groups").prefetch_related("groups").filter(is_active=True).distinct()
```

Which Results:

```
 [{'pk': 4, 'email': 'xxx@gmail.com', 'groups': 4}, {'pk': 4, 'email': 'xxx@gmail.com', 'groups': 6}]
```

but I need queryset which result set like

```
[ {'pk': 4, 'email': 'xxx@gmail.com', 'groups': [4,6]} ]
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do User and Group model look like. Particularly the relationship fields in both. You can edit your question to include this information.

Comment: I am using default `User` and `Group` Models provided by django auth `app`, please visit [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)

Comment: I'm not sure that have your result set that way without iterating over active user queryset to transform it.